# Python reading file, error recognizing dot character

Tags: python

Say I have a lorem ipsum text like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut his semper vivendo
>   apeirian, graece electram sea an, vix assum euismod
>   luptatum ei.
>
> Duo an diceret delicata referrentur. Cum ex mazim 
>   legendos corrumpit, eu fuisset omnesque qui,
>   sit cu populo possit placerat. Lorem dolore ut has,
>   in his ancillae incorrupte. In esse inani nec.

And I want to make this into two paragraphs with two lines, something like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut his semper vivendo apeirian, graece electram sea an, vix assum euismod luptatum ei.
>
> Duo an diceret delicata referrentur. Cum ex mazim  legendos corrumpit, eu fuisset omnesque qui, sit cu populo possit placerat. Lorem dolore ut has, in his ancillae incorrupte. In esse inani nec.

So I wrote my code like this:

```
f = open('lorem ipsum.txt', 'r')
o = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
    if line.endswith("\.\n") == True:
        o.write(line)
    else:
        line = line[:-1] + " "
        o.write(line)
```

Second part of getting rid of newline where it's not necessary works, but the code doesn't seem to recognize dot-newline characters very well. The code ends up writing all text into one line like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut his semper vivendoapeirian, graece electram sea an, vix assum euismodluptatum ei. Duo an diceret delicata referrentur. Cumex mazim legendos corrumpit, eu fuisset omnesque qui, sit cu populo possit placerat. Lorem dolore ut has, inhis ancillae incorrupte. In esse inani nec.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `line.endswith("\.\n")`, you need to use `line.endswith(".\n")`. The parameter to `str.endswith` is not like that of `re` (regular expressions). `.` doesn't carry any special meaning, so does not have to be escaped with `\\`

Comment: @SakshamVarma I swear, last time I tried that it didn't work. Now it suddenly does. Thank you very much anyway. Also, what's the reason for that?

Comment: @FJSK your are confusing string matching with pattern matching.

Comment: @Kay Ah.. I knew that... Rookie mistake, haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try splitting the content whenever there is period along with new line. Replace the other newlines and join them again with newline.

```
f = open('lorem ipsum.txt', 'r')
o = open('output.txt', 'w')
contents = f.read()
new = contents.split('.\n')
o.write('\n'.join([content.replace('\n', '') for content in new]))
```